# Quickbooks Online API to upload multipart attachment gives Could find no Content-Disposition header error

Tags: rest, quickbooks

I'm using golang to build and POST to the endpoint: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/XXXXXX/upload?minorversion=65

and I get the json response:

`{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part","code":"10000"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2023-09-20T14:19:11.865-07:00"}`

when posting the data:

```
--af033f6ccf0906f358c1d8d104c2778d6e2b95f61d13903a25f8f56cc28b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_metadata_1"; filename="RT00404582_10-10-23.pdf"
Content-Type: application/json

{"AttachableRef":[{"EntityRef":{"type":"Bill","value":"153061"}}],"ContentType":"application/pdf","FileName":"RT00404582_10-10-23.pdf"}
--af033f6ccf0906f358c1d8d104c2778d6e2b95f61d13903a25f8f56cc28b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_1"; filename="RT00404582_10-10-23.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

<BINARY FILE DATA>

--af033f6ccf0906f358c1d8d104c2778d6e2b95f61d13903a25f8f56cc28b--
```

I've only seen one example, and the parts match, but the API docs dont have examples or even state what the parts should be formatted as. Does anyone know why it cannot read the headers?